# Horizontal scroll bar when embedding Facebook Page Plugin into site

Tags: html, css, facebook

I am building a website out using Wix and am using an HTML snippet to try and drop in an embedded feed of our public Facebook page. I am using code generated from the Facebook developer tools site (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin).

In the HTML, the width is set for 500px. The "widget" displays at 500px, but the feed of posts below the cover photo seem to take up more space than they are allocated, and as a result there is an annoying horizontal scroll bar (see my site: http://tanglewoodcarehomes.wix.com/tanglewood).

I am far from advanced with HTML and CSS but I'm sure there is some work around...I just need some guidance! Code of the HTML snippet is posted below, any help is much appreciated.

```
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3&appId=2691675043";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-page" width="500" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/tanglewoodcarehomes" data-small-header="true" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true" data-show-posts="true"><div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/tanglewoodcarehomes"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/tanglewoodcarehomes">Tanglewood Care Homes</a></blockquote></div></div>
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Get rid of the unwanted scrollbars by adding the following to your css:

```
.fb-page.fb_iframe_widget {overflow: hidden;}
```

This will remove the outer scrollbars, leaving only the `iframe` vertical scrollbar if it is needed.

Comment: The limitations of the platform don't allow me to edit a separate CSS style sheet so I added CSS to the <head> tag of the snippet. While this does remove the horizontal scrollbar from the display, the feed of posts is still larger than the frame so the horizontal scroll persists. Is there any way to force the content below the cover photo to be the same width as the cover photo to prevent the scrolling issue? Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. There is no way in the Universe you can ever affect the inside of an iframe with your own CSS. That's basically what iframes are for - to shield embedded content from the CSS of the embedding page.

Facebook borked it. They must fix it.